# File path for c# when moved to a memory stick

Tags: c#

sorry first time user and currently learning c# at uni, i'm working on an assignment and i'm trying to get the file path to work on the memory stick as that's what i need to hand it in on, thanks many regards

[image: picture of my memory stick location of the KS1,2,3 files and the program file]

Comment: Add code as formatted text, not as a picture. You also need to describe how it's not behaving as expected.

Comment: Couldn't see the image however, if your c# code is an executable, you can try Application.StartupPath to get the location of the executable directory. Then you can append the relative file name to that path.

Comment: If it were me, I'd copy stuff to my local drive, work there, and (if needed) when finished, copy stuff back to the memory stick.  If you want to find the path to the files, click in the Explorer's address bar and the display will change from "This PC > etc" to a more reasonable path-ish format.

Comment: why are you using the usb label in the path instead of the drive letter?

Comment: Get the location/path of your program with `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (check documentation for difference in behavior between GetEntryAssembly and GetExecutingAssembly) and then work from there; like build the relative path from your program exe to your data files based on that path. Ozan Gunceler's suggestion might work too if your program is a WinForms application, but `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`/`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will work the same way for WinForms, WPF as well as console applications...

Comment: Short answer use F:\ (just to get you going, NOT a long-term fix)

Comment: thank you guys, I've solved the issue and both apologies and appreciation for dealing with my inexperience in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what your question is by I think what you're talking about is **absolute** vs **relative** paths. If you use an absolute path like "C:\users\yourname\blalba\project\stuff", then it's obviously only going to only work on your computer. However, you mostly all of the time want to use **relative** paths. Relative paths have the root directory of the build output files for your project; where your .exe file is built for your project. This is usually in *"projectdir\bin\debug"* or *"projectdir\bin\release"*. So if you put for example a file called *'test.txt'* in that directory, you can simply put the relative path "test.txt" instead of *"C:\users\yourname\blalba\project\bin\debug\test.txt"*. If you were to put *'test.txt'* in the project directory, you can use the relative path *"....\test.txt"*. *"..\"* means navigating one step back.

Comment: Thank you charlie, that has actually answered my question.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The path to the directory containing the files you are looking for is "F:\Mod005244, 1715840". The "1715840 JH" is just the name of the drive. You access different drives via the drive letter. In this case, the drive letter "F" was assigned to your flash drive.

I would suggest making the file path configurable or request input from the user of the program as the drive letter of a flash drive will not always be "F". There are even classes (such as FileBrowserDialog) that will open a graphical file browser dialog and prompt the user to navigate and select a file.